# ESP32 arduino IDE what board to use for ESP32_Devkit_v4

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-ide

I have not found an exact match for the above board but up until now I have used "DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1" without problems
Today trying to use a timer interrupt I got the following:

> #define portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(mux)     vTaskExitCritical(mux)
> ^
> note: in >expansion of macro 'portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR'
> portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux0);
> ^
> exit status 1
> Error compiling for board DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1.

so it seems that there is some difference in the macro.

Can you tell me what board to use?
The offending new bit of code is:

```
int interruptChannel = 0;     // the channel (timer???) being used
int freq             = 10000; // the frequency of the pwm signal
int resolution       = 10;    // 2** 10 = 1024 different duty cycles available
int pwmPin           = 5;     // the pin that the pwm if output on
int dirPin           = 26;    // pin for changing direction

int input;                    // takes in the serial value
int dutyCycle;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
hw_timer_t * timer0 = NULL;

portMUX_TYPE timerMux0 = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;


 
volatile uint8_t fred = 0;
void IRAM_ATTR onTimer0(){
  // Critical Code here
  portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux0);
  fred++;
  //Serial.println(fred)
  portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux0);
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  Serial.println("Program: esp32pwm");    // print out the program name
  
  ledcSetup(interruptChannel,freq,resolution); // set up the channel
  ledcAttachPin(pwmPin,interruptChannel);      // assign the pin
  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);                     // set and assign the direction pin
  digitalWrite(dirPin,LOW);
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // timer 0, MWDT clock period = 12.5 ns * TIMGn_Tx_WDT_CLK_PRESCALE -> 12.5 ns * 80 -> 1000 ns = 1 us, countUp
  timer0 = timerBegin(0, 80, true);  
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer0, &onTimer0, true); // edge (not level) triggered 
  timerAlarmWrite(timer0, 1000000, true); // 2000000 * 1 us = 2 s, autoreload true

  // at least enable the timer alarms
  timerAlarmEnable(timer0); // enable
  
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
/*
 * max rpm of 350 at duty cycle of 1023
 * 350rpm = 5.83/sec
 * circumfrence = .38m
 * therefore a velocity of s metres/sec = s/.38 rpm
 * and a duty cycle of s/.38 /5.83*1023
 * Maximum speed is 2.2 metres/sec
 * 
 */


void loop() {
  
  if( Serial.available()>0){
    
    input = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.print("You typed: " );
    Serial.print(input);Serial.println();
    dutyCycle = int(input/10.0/.38 /5.83*1023);// number entered times 10
    Serial.print("Converts to duty cycle of ");Serial.println(dutyCycle);
    ledcWrite(interruptChannel,dutyCycle);
    Serial.read();
  }
 
}
```

Comment: If your project has been building up until this new code, it's more likely that your code is simply wrong.

Comment: I have added the offending piece of code.

Comment: Your code was compiled successfully in my Arduino IDE. Looks like you don't provide all of the needed code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the whole program